# Is destiny ever used in the plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Compare these two sentences:

> They would have had the chance of choosing their own destiny.
>   They would have had the chance of choosing their own destinies.

Comment: Voting to close as [general reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/destiny).

Answer (score 3):

If they shared a common *destiny*, the first would be appropriate. If they travel divergent paths, the latter.

*[Destinies](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/destiny)* is totally acceptable.